# Why am I losing a node when shuffling a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, shuffle, fisher-yates-shuffle

I have been working on a project. Part of the project needs a shuffled linked list. This function is an implementation of the fisher-yates shuffling algorithm. It puts the linked list into an array. Then it shuffles it. Then relinks it.

After some testing I have found that sometimes when I shuffle a linked list, I lose a node somewhere. I have done some testing with ubsan and asan. They both show nothing. I used to have a issue with this function causing a segfault later on. The segfault was causing by not relinking the linked list correctly. More specifically the last node before shuffling in the linked list was not relinked correctly. I fixed that somewhat by making the list circular before shuffling it.

Here is the code used for shuffling along with the swap and relink functions:

```
linked_node* shuffle(linked_node* head) {
    int count = 0;
    linked_node* count_head = head;
    while (count_head != NULL) {
        count++;
        count_head = count_head->next;
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG 
        fprintf(stderr, "count: %i\r\n", count);
    #endif

    linked_node** array = malloc(count * sizeof(linked_node*));

    int i = 0;

    linked_node* add_head = head;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        array[i] = add_head;
        add_head = add_head->next;
    }
    
    //made circluar to prevent segfault with the last node
    array[count - 1]->next = head;

    srand48(time(NULL));



    for (int j = count - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        int random = lrand48() % (j+1);

        array_swap(&array[j], &array[random]);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k > count - 1; k++) {
        relink(array[k], array[k + 1]);
    }

    linked_node* new_head = array[0];

    //made circular for ease of use later
    array[count - 1]->next = new_head;

    free(array);

    return new_head;
}

static inline void relink(linked_node* prev, linked_node* next) {
    if (prev != NULL && next != NULL) {
        prev->next = next;
    }
}

void array_swap(linked_node** a, linked_node** b) {
    linked_node* temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Use pen and paper to draw up the list and all operations on it you do on the list (using squares for nodes, and arrows for the links, erasing and redrawing the arrows as needed) while stepping through the code statement by statement in a debugger. Should hopefully help you solve the problem.

Comment: I don't have time to look at this right now, but my gut tells me it's too much code.  The less code, the better. And your top function is definitely too long.  It needs to be refactored into smaller functions.  Sometimes refactoring buggy code helps you find the bug.... just because the refactoring forces you to break the problem into smaller pieces in your head and you discover a misplaced assumption.  Just the fact that you'll be forced into naming the smaller functions will help you reason about what's going on.

Comment: And I hope it's not nitpicking, but I kind of felt a red flag when I read that you changed the code to "fix the segfault".  That indicates to me that you didn't totally understand why the segfault was happening.  You don't usually want to "fix a segfault", rather you want to use the segfault to help you understand your logic error and fix that.

Just like I wouldn't want to hear a cardiologist say he "fixed the chest pain"

Comment: the function shuffle behave weird, it expect to get linked list with null terminator but return circular linked list. Are you sure that what your main function expects? we are missing here your main function that creating the linked list and calling shuffle, maybe the bug ia there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in this for loop

```
for (int k = 0; k > count - 1; k++) {
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    relink(array[k], array[k + 1]);
}
```

It seems you mean

```
for (int k = 0; k < count - 1; k++) {
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    relink(array[k], array[k + 1]);
}
```

Also this statement

```
//made circluar to prevent segfault with the last node
array[count - 1]->next = head;
```

is redundant and actually does not have an effect. Remove it.

This statement

```
//made circular for ease of use later
array[count - 1]->next = new_head;
```

could be substituted for this statement

```
array[count - 1]->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Isn't that a closure reason?

Comment: @trincot Let's wait what the author of the question will say.

Comment: Didn't know that was the procedure to follow in case of a typo question :/

Comment: @trincot It can be a typo in the code typed in the question not in his real code. If so then I will delete my answer.

Comment: In that case I would have thought a comment asking for clarification was the appropriate action.